# Processing a two-dimensional array in Angular 7. ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, ngfor

How to handle a two-dimensional array using ngFor? 
[I receive here such array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33JQq.png)

As a result, I need to get the blocks in which the data from the array is displayed in order. That is, in the case of an array that is represented on the screen, there would be 10 blocks.
**Example:**

```
<div>
  <span>Yandex</span>
  <span>Yandex.N.V....</span>
  <span>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yandex</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Yandex Browser</span>
  <span>IPA:...</span>
  <span>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yandex_Browser</span>
</div>
```

etc.

I do it that way.

```
<h3>Get Articles</h3>
<div>
  <div *ngIf="articles">
    <div *ngFor="let article of articles">
      <span>{{ article[1] }}</span>
      <span>{{ article[2] }}</span>
      <span>{{ article[3] }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand that this is wrong, but I can not find my stupid mistake.
The output is either an error or a [strange conclusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti0us.png).

**search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Article, ArticlesService } from '../../services/articles.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
  providers: [ArticlesService]
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private articlesServices: ArticlesService) { }

  searchQuery: string;
  limit: number;

  error: any;
  articles: { };

  // noinspection JSMethodCanBeStatic
  getUrl(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='
      + searchQuery + '&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  showArticles() {
    this.articlesServices.getArticles(this.getUrl(this.searchQuery))
      .subscribe(
        (data: Article) => this.articles = Object.values({
          title: data[0],
          collection: data[1],
          description: data[2],
          links: data[3]
        }),
        error => this.error = error
      );
    console.log(this.articles);
  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**article.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Article, ArticleInfo, ArticlesService} from '../../services/articles.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-articles',
  templateUrl: './articles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articles.component.css'],
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() articles: Article;
  @Input() searchQuery: string;

  constructor(private articlesServices: ArticlesService) { }

  information: ArticleInfo;

  getUrl(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=' +
      searchQuery + '&utf8=&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  showArticlesInformation() {
    this.articlesServices.getArticlesInfo(this.getUrl(this.searchQuery))
      .subscribe(
        (data: ArticleInfo) => this.information = {
          query: data.query.search
        }
      );
    console.log(this.information);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**article.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Article {
  title: string;
  collection: string[];
  description: string[];
  links: string[];
}

export interface ArticleInfo {
  query: {
    search
  };
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticlesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArticles(url) {
    return this.http.get(url)
      .pipe(
        retry(3),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  getArticlesInfo(url) {
    return this.http.get<ArticleInfo>(url);
  }

  // noinspection JSMethodCanBeStatic
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

[Come 2D array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRc0P.png)

[Then it should turn out like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtR4R.png)

Comment: Is `articles` your 2D array?

Comment: Yes. `articles: [string, string[], string[], string[]`

Comment: Tried nested loops?

Comment: Yes. If you use this, there will be an error. `<div *ngFor="let article of articles"><div *ngFor=let collection of article[1]>{{ collection }}</div></div>`

Comment: There is syntax mistake in that. I've given an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
<div>
    {{articles[0]}}
</div>
<div *ngFor="let article of articles[1]; let i=index">
    <span>
        {{article}}
    </span>
    <span *ngFor="let info1 of articles[2]; let j=index" [hidden]="i!=j">
        {{info1}}
    </span>
    <span *ngFor="let info2 of articles[3]; let k=index" [hidden]="i!=k">
        {{info2}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the error all the same takes off
_"Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Yandex' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"_

Comment: I think your problem is obvious, in your example you mentioned the first index is a string. While in this code the first index is expected to be array.

Comment: Quote: `[string, string[], string[], string[]` as you can see here first index is string, and that is why it fails.

Comment: @IlyaNizovcev Only the first index is string?

Comment: @Arcteezy yes it is

Comment: @enf0rcer Yes you are right. I did not notice this stupid mistake. I fixed this, but using the code above prints the entire 2D array. And I need to give in the format that I wrote

Comment: @Arcteezy Thank you very much! This fixed the error, but displays the contents of the entire 2D array.

Comment: @IlyaNizovcev What is your expected output? Can you provide a screenshot.

Comment: @Arcteezy I need to display first all the first elements of the arrays in the 2D array, then the second, etc.
Now I will show in the screenshot

Comment: @IlyaNizovcev I figured it out. One question : Is the articles always going to be of structure `{ string, string[10], string[10], string[10] }`?

Comment: @Arcteezy No not always. It will depend on the user's choice, it sets the number that returns wikipedia api. Will always be like this `{ string, string[n], string[n], string[n] }` where n is the number set by the user

Comment: @IlyaNizovcev It will always have three string arrays ,right? And all their lengths will be same?

Comment: @Arcteezy yes it is

Comment: @IlyaNizovcev I've updated my answer. See if it works as your requirement.

Comment: @Arcteezy Yes, it works. Thank you so much, you saved me! I suffered with this for two days before writing here. :)

Comment: Happy to help :D

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the result into ***Observable*** and into the html file use ***async*** pipe.

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles | async">
```

In your **search.component.ts**

```
articles : Observable<Article>;
...
this.articles = this.articlesServices.getArticles(this.getUrl(this.searchQuery)).catch(error => this.error = error );
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you.
Could you please explain in more detail? I'm still completely new

Comment: @Ilya Nizovcev I've  made changes through the code. Please go through